# Real name of the "container_of" pattern

Tags: c, design-patterns, containers

E.g. in Linux driver development one can find the [`container_of`](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html) macro. In essence it is the reverse operator to an `->`, yielding the pointer to the containing structure if you got a pointer to a member.

Besides from Greg Kroah's blog I found this pattern in the [list](https://github.com/mehlis/Pintos/blob/621497/src/lib/kernel/list.h) and [hash](https://github.com/mehlis/Pintos/blob/621497/src/lib/kernel/hash.h) implementation of Pintos.

Comment: Just to add to your list, Windows has the similar `CONTAINING_RECORD` macro.  I don't know of a generic name for the 'pattern'.

Comment: When used to implement container data structures, boost calls this technique "intrusive containers" in the C++ world. Though  container_of is more general and useful in other contexts than to implement general data structures such as lists and hash tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real name of this pattern is "container_of()." Attempting to fit this C-ism into a Java or C++ design pattern taxonomy is futile. The point is not to chain responsibility, or to designate or delegate anything. If you must think in these terms then it's a "messy generalized inheritance." If you don't have to think in these terms then it's a lot less messy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's a not-very featureful [`Chain Of Responsibility`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). The only reason you need a pointer back to your parent container structure is to place parent container functionality within reach of the contained elements.  As such, it *could* be seen as an implementation detail required to allow a request to trickle up the "chain" until it gets handled at the correct "level".

With a container / contained relationship, that "correct" level is just one level up, and the trickle up doesn't go through enough levels (since there is only one level) to generate much interest as an ideal example of the pattern. Still, the general ideas behind `Chain of Responsibility` still hold; a request is made at a point in the chain which cannot handle it, and is handled at a different point in the change which can.

With a small non-generic container / contained relationship, the coupling of this two link chain can get quite tight.  For example, your examples lack of a generic "command" handling framework (since the command language set is small), and such a framework generally requires (for type safety) a Command / Message Object.  That's a lot of overhead, for a list that just wants to let it's elements directly notify at the element level that they want to be removed from the list.

And yes, [there is a C2 pattern's page for it](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ChainOfResponsibilityPattern)... If you agree with my reasoning.